# Get ListView item when button in row is clicked

Tags: c#, listview

I have a `ListView` that creates a table. Each row in the table has two buttons - Delete and Modify. I'm firing a click event for each button but I'm not sure how to get a handle to the data in the row that the button was clicked.

aspx

```
<asp:ListView runat="server" ID="usersListView">
    <LayoutTemplate>
        <table class="table table-striped">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>User Name</th>
                    <th>Email</th>
                    <th>Role</th>
                    <th>Actions</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="groupPlaceHolder"/>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </LayoutTemplate>
    <GroupTemplate>
        <tr>
            <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="itemPlaceHolder"/>
        </tr>
    </GroupTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <td><%# Eval("user.UserName") %></td>
        <td><%# Eval("user.Email") %></td>
        <td><%# Eval("roles") %></td>
        <td>
            <button runat="server" id="modify" class="btn btn-mini" title="Modify" onclick="modify_OnClick">
                <i class="icon-edit"></i>
            </button>&nbsp;
            <button runat="server" id="delete" class="btn btn-mini" title="Delete" onclick="delete_OnClick">
                <i class="icon-trash"></i>
            </button>
        </td>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

aspx.cs

```
public void delete_Onclick(object sender, EventArgs e) {

}

public void modify_Onclick(object sender, EventArgs e) {

}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I will try to answer the question in the title since i don't understand the question itself.

You can cast the the `sender` to the Button. The Button's `NamingContainer` is the [`ListViewItem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listviewitem.aspx). You can use this to get all your other control in that item by using `item.FindControl("OtherControlID")`.

For example;

```
public void delete_Onclick(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    var btn = (Button)sender;
    var item = (ListViewItem)btn.NamingContainer;
    // find other controls:
    var btnModify = (Button)item.FindControl("modify");
}
```

You cannot find text that is not in a server control. But you could use a `LiteralControl` or `Label` to display the username or email.

```
<td><asp:Label id="Label1" runat="server"
          Text='<%# Eval("user.UserName") %>' />
</td>
```

Now you can use `FindControl` as shown above to get a reference to the label in codebehind.

Comment: once I have `item` shouldn't I be able to get the 'User Name' column for that selected row?

Comment: You cannot find text that is not in a server control. But you could use a LiteralControl or Label instead. Edited my answer.

Comment: couldn't I just add a runat="server" to the `td` and access it that way?

Comment: @bflemi3: oh yes, it should work either with `runat="server"` and ID, i think you can cast it to `HtmlTableCell` and use `InnerText` then.

Answer (score 1):

I know 2 solutions:

---

1-command name and command argument as below

---

2-**you can use links instead of buttons** and send queryString that include 
the id of your record to the same page u are,and take querystring in 
code behind(page load) and use it for delete sqlcommadns or redirect it to another page for 
editing purposes and finally Response.Redirect() again to the same page that you are.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using a GridView since the data is tabular. At any rate, you can implement the ItemCommand event. The [MSDN page has an example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.itemcommand.aspx).

You can customize `CommandName` and the `CommandArgument` properties of an `Button` control. The CommandArgument can be made to contain some ID or a relevant piece of information.